# postgres find whether json path exists

Tags: json, postgresql, path, psql, jsonb

I want to find whether a specific path exists in a jsonb value using a psql query.

For example, for this path: `{"333":"opc":["1333"]}`

This value should return true:

```
'{"333":{"opc":[{"1333":"3787"}]}}'
```

But these values should return false:

- `'{"333":{"opc":[{"104":"3787"}]}}'`
- `'{"54":{"opc":[{"1333":"3787"},{"1334":"37"}]}}'`
- `'{"333":{"opc":[]}}'`

I've tried some variations using the `@>` operator but couldn't quite get the right syntax.

ex:

```
select 
  '{"333":{"opc":[{"1333":"3787"},{"1334":"37"}]}}'::jsonb @>   
  '{"333":{"opc":[{"1333"}]}}'::jsonb
```

this gives me an invalid syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
select 
  case when
    (select e->'1333' from json_array_elements(data->'333'->'opc') e) is not null
    then true
    else false
  end as status
from t 
;
```

?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2c794/17

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply. when I try your suggestion I get the following error... ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression. Let me give it a bit more testing and I will post again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended up using this:

select * from (select jsonb_array_elements(data->'333'->'opc')->'1333' as value from t ) e where e.value is not null